# Determine size of a sample from gnuradio src object in python

Tags: python, gnuradio

Say I have a gnuradio src object in python, e.g.,:

```
src = analog.sig_source_c(sim_sam_rate, analog.GR_SIN_WAVE, sine_prms['frq_in_hz'],
                                  sine_prms['mag'], sine_prms['offset'])
```

or

```
src = blocks.vector_source_f(sine_sam)
```

How can I determine from src the size of a single source sample?  In the first example, it would be gr.sizeof_gr_complex (or 8) and in the second example gr.sizeof_float (or 4) since sine_sam are samples of a real sinewave.

The context is that I'm trying to use gnuradio without companion.  I'd like to create a throttle, which requires knowledge of the size of the samples.  I would like to obtain that information from the src object itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
src.output_signature().sizeof_steam_items()
```

gives a tuple containing the sizes of each output.